# Serving static files Go seems inefficient..or maybe its just me :-)

Tags: go

Over months I've read tons of articles about Go and best practices.  Among those articles are numerous google searches and SOF searches regarding how to and the best way to serve static files.

This is what I currently have

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static/"))
myRouter.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))

myRouter.PathPrefix("/admin/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/admin/static/", fs))
myRouter.PathPrefix("/admin/accounts/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/admin/accounts/static/", fs))
myRouter.PathPrefix("/admin/admin_tools/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/admin/admin_tools/static/", fs))
myRouter.PathPrefix("/admin/audit_tools/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/admin/audit_tools/static/", fs))
myRouter.PathPrefix("/admin/demand/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/admin/demand/static/", fs))
myRouter.PathPrefix("/admin/optimization/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/admin/optimization/static/", fs))
myRouter.PathPrefix("/admin/reports/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/admin/reports/static/", fs))
myRouter.PathPrefix("/admin/setups/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/admin/setups/static/", fs))
myRouter.PathPrefix("/admin/queue/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/admin/queue/static/", fs))
myRouter.PathPrefix("/admin/tagservers/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/admin/tagservers/static/", fs))
myRouter.PathPrefix("/admin/client/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/admin/client/static/", fs))
myRouter.PathPrefix("/client/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/client/static/", fs))
```

My issue with this is that for **every** path I have to add a new line to cover where the static files come from.  Most examples show how it's done when you have a single landing page with no real navigations built into it. Coming from a Python background I suppose I was bit spoiled with some of the lightweight frameworks, such as Flask and Tornado, where one just points to the static folder once.

Another issue with this current setup is it doesn't play nice with NGINX.  Again with frameworks like Flask and Tornado, all you have to do in NGINX is set the static location once.  With Go I have to set the static location just like the code above (by defining each path).

**Has anyone found a better way to serve static files?**  I know in theory a function could probably be written to automate it, but it wouldn't really change the fact that each path has to be accounted for on the app level and NGINX level.

**UPDATE:** In reply to @mkopriva I've attached two screenshots.  The first is of the browser running the app with dev tools open to show the 404s on the static files. The Second is of the server code, to produce those errors all I did was comment out one line.  The line that handles the audit_tools path. If I uncomment it everything routes no problem.

[image: Browser Errors]
[image: Server code with commented out line]

Edit, both @mkopriva and @sberry did a great job. I wish I could pick two correct answers.

Comment: What's the purpose of handling all those separate paths if all your static files live in one folder? Your first `myRouter.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))` should be enough to serve any file inside `/statict/`.

Comment: You would think, but that is not the case. I promise you if you remove the other paths then it will only serve files on the root path. / however when you have real navigation on a page /admin/reports/some_report_type go will not be able to locate the files. If you dont believe me try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All those `PathPrefix` and `StripPrefix` calls seem to me to be functionally pointless. If your static directory is inside your Go project and its structure looks something like this:

```
.
├── main.go
└── static
    ├── admin
    │   ├── accounts
    │   │   └── file.txt
    │   ├── file.txt
    │   └── reports
    │       └── file.txt
    └── file.txt
```

then to serve files from that static directory with Go, all you should really need is this.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static/"))
    http.Handle("/", fs)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've attached screen shots of how the errors I get when I don't add each path

Comment: @reticentroot fix your html `script`, `link`, and `a` links, you are linking by using relative paths, use absolute paths instead. Instead of `<script type="text/javascript" src="static/foobar.js"></script>` use `<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/foobar.js"></script>`

Comment: bro...  no words LOL.. its one of those issues that annoyed me..forget about it.. see it again think about it, etc.  My title was spot on.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using nginx to do this work then you don't need Go to do it too (unless you want to be able to run standalone without nginx).  If that is the case then you can use a Path call instead of PathPrefix so you can do pattern matching.

If you are just trying to do this via nginx then something like this should work:

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    location ~* ^/static/ {
        root /path/to/directory/containing_static;
    }

    location  ~* ^.*/static/(.*)$ {
        rewrite "^.*/static/(.*)$" /static/$1 last;
    }


    location @forward_to_app {
       # send to your go app here
    }

  }
```

You can probably do without the rewrite, but that was an easy approach to take.

Comment: You need both go and ngnix to do it. Go must server static files when you're working local. Nginx serves in production.

Comment: Regardless of the Go stuff, ill try this in the test production environment. Because if this works at least that's half the issue taken care of. Ill comment back if that solves the repitition on the nginx level.

Comment: @reticentroot Why must you serve static files with the go server if running locally?  Your dev environment should be a "reasonable facsimile of production".  I use docker for this, but there are other tools out there.  If I'm going to use nginx/apache as a reverse proxy in production, I'm certainly going to do it in development as well.

Comment: Running locally means running on my mac(s) we don't use docker. Local so in my local environment we I just spin up the server go run server.go and start coding or editing, push to git, pull on the server, go clean, go build server.go, restart process. All in that means that when I run it local go is serving the static files and in production NGINX is.

Comment: Either way, that nginx stuff you wrote above, worked like a charm, I was able to work with just this lines.