# How to define one static folder for all routes

Tags: go, gorilla

I use [github.com/gorilla/mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) router and I need include my static files for all routes or notFound routes.
Now refreshing only page by `/` works but other urls doesn't.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "crudgo/backend/home"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
  )

func main() {
     http.FileServer(http.Dir("./public/p/dist"))
     log.Println("Listening...")

     router := mux.NewRouter();

     home.HomeRoute(router)

     router.PathPrefix("/{_:.*}").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("./public/p/dist")))

     http.ListenAndServe("localhost:3000", router)
}
```

Comment: See here for a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132005/serving-static-files-go-seems-inefficient-or-maybe-its-just-me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serving static files Go seems inefficient..or maybe its just me :-)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132005/serving-static-files-go-seems-inefficient-or-maybe-its-just-me)